# Evolution crashing

Tags: crash, evolution

I upgraded to 20.04LTS last week and the last day or two Evolution starts to crash randomly.  Sometimes it crashes as soon as it starts up.  Sometimes it runs for a while and then crashes.

When I ran it in the terminal I get a segmentation fault.  Here is the backtrace from the core:

```
core was generated by `evolution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f2de8875d00 (LWP 62619))]
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007f2df38785dc in g_hash_table_lookup ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f2deffe8758 in gdk_x11_atom_to_xatom_for_display ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
#3  0x00007f2dccb52227 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/evolution/plugins/liborg-freedesktop-evolution-indicator.so
#4  0x00007f2dccb52938 in org_gnome_mail_new_notify ()
   from /usr/lib/evolution/plugins/liborg-freedesktop-evolution-indicator.so
#5  0x00007f2df038d6d4 in e_event_emit ()
   from /usr/lib/evolution/libevolution-util.so.0
#6  0x00007f2dcdbeca88 in ?? () from /usr/lib/evolution/libevolution-mail.so.0
#7  0x00007f2dee784ff5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7
#8  0x00007f2dee78440a in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7
#9  0x00007f2df3977806 in g_cclosure_marshal_generic_va ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#10 0x00007f2df3976a56 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#11 0x00007f2df3995b28 in g_signal_emit_valist ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#12 0x00007f2df39960d3 in g_signal_emit ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#13 0x00007f2de4105a2b in ?? () from /usr/lib/evolution/libemail-engine.so.0
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--c
#14 0x00007f2df388ae8e in g_main_context_dispatch () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#15 0x00007f2df388b240 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#16 0x00007f2df388b533 in g_main_loop_run () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#17 0x00007f2df3e5e30d in gtk_main () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#18 0x000055d32cd4f768 in main ()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug report that says removing evolution-indicator would work:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/1725315

That seems to fix it for now.